# Google Analytics for Firebase: How to analyze events

Tags: ios, firebase, analytics, analysis, firebase-analytics

I have built an iOS app recently, at the moment I have like 2k downloads per day. I am at the moment where I want to track all the events in my app so I can know how to improve the conversion rate and user experience.

I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to use Firebase correctly to track events, but didn't find a solution that suits me. 
I know I can track events, I know I can track any sort of information, but I can't seem to find a way to filter through all the information to know what action leads a purchase, what features are used the least by the users.

My app is free, but after you download it you can purchase the pro version, there are a few subscription options that the user can choose, and the PRO version can be purchased from many places in the app.

What I want to know is for example: How many people buy the pro version from the "Settings" screen, and many people buy from the "Remove ads" button.

I thought it should be in the Funnels tab in firebase but it does something else.

BigQuery isn't an option for me at the moment because I need a simple and visual way to display graphs to my marketing team.

Comment: Have a look at [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/), which can visualize the data from BigQuery. There is even a template that reproduces (some of) the default analytics reports that Firebase shows.

Answer (score 2):

> BigQuery isn't an option for me at the moment because I need a simple and visual way to display graphs to my marketing team.

Check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/finding-data-insights-faster-with-bigquery-and-gcp-marketplace-solutions) for tools which can solve your problem

I found this helpful

> [Matillion ETL for BigQuery](https://www.matillion.com/etl-for-bigquery/): Matillion transforms data, across its various locations and forms, into BigQuery, enabling users to make informed, data-driven decisions
>
> [SuperQuery AI](https://web.superquery.io/): This powerful SQL integrated development environment for BigQuery includes AI that optimizes queries in real time
>
> [Striim](https://www.striim.com/): This is an end-to-end data integration platform that enables continuous ingestion of real-time data
>
> Looker: Looker connects directly to your BigQuery instance and optimizes data discovery within BigQuery itself

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21822214)

Comment: I updated my answer per your suggestion